# How to do if x in y in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I have this coffeescript:

```
y = Object
y.x = true;
result = false
if 'x' in y
    result = true
```

Which generates this javascript:

```
var result, y,
__indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) { for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {   if (i in this && this[i] === item) return i; } return -1; };

y = Object;

y.x = true;

result = false;

if (__indexOf.call(y, 'x') >= 0) {
   result = true;
}
```

Clearly the result should be true but the javascript generated does not return this result. I know I could just escape the section as javascript but that seems hacky. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out that I need to use 'of' instead of 'in'.

Comment: If you solved the question on your own feel free to mark your answer as correct, so other user could later easily see what to do.